# How do I make image shrink to flex column?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create an 8-column flex grid that contains images that line breaks after 8 items. I want the images to stay the width of the column. However, the image is holding onto its native size and not reducing to the size of the column, which is set a 12.5% with `flex-basis`

I've tried adding a `max-width` to the image but they still hold onto their native size.

My question is; how can I contain images within their 12.5% column regardless of how big the image is?

[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/mrthomason/pen/KKxMXrK)

```css
.container {
  max-width: 80%
}

.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 12.5%;
}

.flex-img {
  max-width 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-grid">
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases where the size of an element is coming from the outside (parent) and doesn't rely on the intrinsic size, it is often the better idea to use a `grid`.

Here is how I edit your code to make it work.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 80%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

.img-wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `max-width: 100%` on the image itself to restrict it to its containers width, and apply `width: 12.5%` and `box-sizing: border-box` to those containers, i.e. the `.flex-img` divs:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 80%
}

.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 12.5%;
}
.flex-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-grid">
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-img">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```